# iPhone Development : Magnifying glass of a UITextField is empty

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

The Magnifying glass shows up, but is empty (white)! 
On iOS simulator, it is working fine.

Any clue ?

Thanks,

Jonathan.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for having asked, but after a LOT of research, I found this question already :

[In iOS7 Text Magnifier isn't working app wide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19039581/in-ios7-text-magnifier-isnt-working-app-wide)

For me, the problem was also that for historical reason, another UIWindow object was instanciated.

j.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's due to the frames not being with the right size in the UI editor at Xcode.

Check for warnings of compilation time and see if you have problems in your storyboards or xib files.

Also, are you running iOS simulator of the same type of your device? If not, you might be missing to test it there also!